# avoid 302 response when using nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx

I have the below configuration. Note that `/images` is mapped to `/app/images` on the destination server, and `/app` is left intact:

```
location /app {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
location /images {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/app/images;
}
```

I want to use a single `location`:

```
location ~ ^/(app|images) {
    rewrite    ^/images /app/images last;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

But this sends a 302 to `/app/images` to the client in response to `/images` URLs. I want it to do it "internally" and just map the `/images` to `/app/images`. How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `break` so that the modified URI continues to be processed within the same location block. For example:

```
location ~ ^/(app|images) {
    rewrite ^/images /app$uri break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: Thanks. With `break` I still get a redirect on the client..

Comment: I think we should probably append the rest of the URI. You could capture `(.*)` or just stick `$uri` after `/app` as shown in the updated answer.